# How to change queue of currently running hadoop job?

Tags: hadoop, resources, share, jobs

My hadoop job was running over 10 hours but since I put it in wrong queue, the containers are kept getting killed by the scheduler.

How do I change the queue of currently running hadoop job without restarting it?

Thank you

Comment: You can change the queue with commands but I doubt you can do it for running process.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

if running Yarn you can change the current job's queue by

```
yarn application -movetoqueue <app_id> -queue <queue_name>
```